# Java Spring issue with java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException

Tags: java, multithreading, email

I have an app in Java which is giving me this error (java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException) when I call two different times the same method while the first one is still running....

For the solution I read, I should create a new instance of the Thread, but I think that it is not an option for me as I'm Autowiring all the classes... So if I forced to create a new instance, the other services (which are inside the thread) won't be instanciated.

So, let go to the code...

In my spring-config.xml I added the following bean so I can access to EmailThread (Which is the thread I want to create to send emails) without stopping the app (as the emails takes several seconds to be sent)

```
<bean id="emailThread" class="com.cobranzasmoviles.services.EmailThread"></bean>
```

This is my EmailThread

```
@Component
public class EmailThread extends Thread {

    Client client;
    CollectionBO collection;
    boolean confirmation;

    @Autowired
    private EmailService emailService;

    public void update(Client client, CollectionBO collection, boolean confirmation){
        this.client = client;
        this.collection = collection;
        this.confirmation = confirmation;
    }    

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            if(this.client != null && this.collection != null)
                emailService.send(this.client, this.collection, this.confirmation);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is how I call it (if I remove the while and the timeout, I get the error I meantioned)

```
@Autowired
EmailThread emailThread;
private void sendEmail(Client client, CollectionBO collection, boolean confirmation){
        try {
            this.emailThread.update(client, collection, false);
            State state = this.emailThread.getState();
            while(!state.name().equalsIgnoreCase("NEW") && !state.name().equalsIgnoreCase("TERMINATED"))
                Timeout.seconds(1000);
            this.emailThread.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The issue with this solution is that I'm stopping the app execution waiting for the state to change finalized.

So as you can see, I cannot simple do new EmailThread()... Is there any solution? I'm using the wrong strategy to send emails?

---

UPD

I changed my method to

```
@Async
    private void sendEmailService(Client client, CollectionBO collection, boolean confirmation){
        try {
//          this.emailThread.update(client, collection, false);
//          State state = this.emailThread.getState();
//          while(!state.name().equalsIgnoreCase("NEW") && !state.name().equalsIgnoreCase("TERMINATED"))
//              Timeout.seconds(1000);
//          this.emailThread.start();
            this.emailService.send(client, collection, confirmation);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

But the app is still waiting for the email to be sent to continue with the execution... Am I missing something?

I'm calling the method with:

```
this.sendEmailService(client, colResponse, false);
```

Is the @Async enough or should I add anything else?

UDT2:

I added @EnableAsync on my WebConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableAsync
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass=true)
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
```

In one class I'm calling the @Async method in this way

```
this.emailService.send(client, colResponse, true);
```

In the interface I added teh @Async as well (not sure if required)

```
@Async
    public void send(Client client, CollectionBO collection, boolean confirmation) throws Exception;
```

And in the method implementation also added the @Async

```
@Async
    public void send(Client client, CollectionBO collection, boolean confirmation) {
```

But it is not working.. I mean, the app still wait for the email to be sent to complete the flow. The email is the last step in the flow, so I'm trying to send the response to the frontend, without waiting for the email.
But I don;t get any response until the email is sent.

Comment: You might want to re-scope your bean. All beans are singleton by default, so your thread would be in an illegal state when accessed again. Try to scope as prototype and proxy appropriately with the caller if so required.

Comment: I think it is not a good idea to start separate threads in a spring container by yourself. Instead you can use the @Asnc annotation from spring to call methods asynchonous.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to wait for the `emailService` to perform the `send` operation, you could annotate it with `@Async`. As the method is void, you don't need to handle the `Future` provided by the proxy, so the change has minimum impact.

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Async.html

Comment: I tried with that, but it's not working.. the execution is stopped until the email is sent.. Please check the update in the post... Am I missing something?

Comment: You should also add the `@EnableAsync` annotation on a configuration class. Check: http://www.baeldung.com/spring-async

Comment: Really nice article, I read it and I learnt some things from there... I adedd the EnableAsync, the Async method I'm calling is public and it is in a different class... but anyway, the app is waiting for the email to send back the response to the backend. COuld you please check UDT2 in the post?